# Azure Pricing to a Customer

Tags: azure

Want to use Windows Azure for a couple of projects but as I haven't used it yet I am wondering how I can work out what I need to charge the end client as the cost can fluctuate based on usage/storage etc.

I would appreciate any comments on how others have firstly quoted costs when suggesting Azure to an end customer and how they charge for each month i.e. set monthly figure subject to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only get between your customer and the Azure charges if you are building a Software as a Service application or some similar multi-tenant application. In these cases what you charge should only be loosely related to Azure charges and may be difficult to figure out. You could, for example, measure outgoing bytes per tenant, but with difficulty.

If you are building an application on Azure for one customer, there is no reason to become a charges intermediary. Sit the customer down and walk them through setting up an Azure account - with their own credit card. Once they have the account created, they can make you an administrator. Have Microsoft invoice the customer directly and don't get involved. There are a few reasons for this:

- Customer knowledge and control of costs is one of the benefits of the cloud. Having an educated customer, that understands and controls their costs is a good customer to have - and removes a lot of complicated explaining.
- Azure pricing is public. If you add a margin the customer may feel ripped off.
- You have no idea of the future load of the application and cannot take the risk on setting a fixed price. If you have the cash to take the risk, the price that you will charge to cover that risk will make it too expensive.

To start off with, using the [Azure pricing calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) is fine. The pricing calculator breaks down when doing more complex things, but for an initial quote it is good enough. As a developer you should have an idea of the number of roles, databases, and so on, to feed into the initial pricing calculation.

Many things, and many architectural decisions affect the costs, so the cost model has to be continuously maintained and updated. One of the biggest factors is the load, which at least at the beginning, you probably have no medium-term clue what it is. Have a look at [CALM](https://github.com/projectcalm/Azure-EN), and reference the lifecycle and cost models for more insight.

If you feel you have to generate ongoing income from the application, rather enter into a support agreement using a flat rate or your own model (say $20 per month per role).

In summary, use the pricing calculator for ballpark figures, but let Microsoft bill the customer directly.

Comment: A good detailed answer thank you.